# Printing elements of a 2D array with columns and rows

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

Im new to java and I am trying to print elements I got from a selection sort algorithm both by columns and by rows.
The expected output for an unsorted matrix can be by rows
486                             123                  147
927                     to      456 (rows)     or    258 (columns)
135 (unsorted)                  789                  369
Thanks in advance! Please no professional solutions since I am a student.

```
public void sort(boolean byColumn)
{
    double[] temp = null;
    double placeHolder = 0.0;
    int total = 0;
    int index = 0;

    /* Incrementing the total to use for the length of the temporary array. */
    for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++) 
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[rows].length; columns++)
        {
            total++;
        }
    }

    temp = new double[total];

    /* This nested for loop converts the indices of mdArray to one long temp array. */
    for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++) 
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[rows].length; columns++)
        {
            temp[index] = mdArray[rows][columns];
            index++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) // Sorting the temporary array using selection sort. 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < temp.length; j++)
        {
            if (temp[j] < temp[i])
            {
                placeHolder = temp[i];
                temp[i] = temp[j];
                temp[j] = placeHolder;
            }
        }
    }
    index = 0;

    if (byColumn) // Sorting the invoking array by column.
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++) // Puts sorted elements back into mdArray.
        {
            for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[rows].length; columns++)
            {
                mdArray[rows][columns] = temp[index];
                index++;
            }
        }

        for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[rows].length; columns++)
            {
                System.out.print(mdArray[rows][columns] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    else if (!byColumn) // Sorting the invoking by row.
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[columns].length; columns++)
        {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++)
            {
                mdArray[columns][rows] = temp[index];
                index++;
            }
        }

        for (int rows = 0; rows < mdArray.length; rows++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int columns = 0; columns < mdArray[rows].length; columns++)
            {
                System.out.print(mdArray[rows][columns] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    else if (byColumn && isRagged()) // 
        System.out.println("Cannot sort ragged arrays by column.");



}
```

Comment: and what is not working exactly? I have not checked it, but what you are trying to do should work with your code, provided there is no error in it...

Comment: Both things are printing out by the same which is: 123 456 789

Comment: I believe they are both printing in rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if you add comment line to your code, this is definetly means, that it is better to extract code part to the separate method.

In your case, I reccomend to implement two more methods: `sortByColumn(int[][] arr)` and `sortByRow(int[][] arr)`, because using `sort(arr, true)` is not so clear at the first sight (what exactly `true` means).

Public methods for the clients (clear to use):

```
public static void sortByColumn(int[][] arr) {
    sort(arr, true);
}

public static void sortByRow(int[][] arr) {
    sort(arr, false);
}
```

Sort implementation (proctected and not available to the client directly):

```
prvate static void sort(int[][] arr, boolean byColumn) {
    int[] temp = convertToSimpleArray(arr);

    selectionSort(temp);

    if (byColumn) {
        for (int row = 0, i = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
                arr[row][col] = temp[i++];
    } else {
        for (int col = 0, i = 0; i < temp.length; col++)
            for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
                if (col < arr[row].length)
                    arr[row][col] = temp[i++];
    }
}
```

Method for create 1D array from given 2D array:

```
private static int[] convertToSimpleArray(int[][] arr) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
            total++;

    int[] res = new int[total];

    for (int row = 0, i = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
            res[i++] = arr[row][col];

    return res;
}
```

Method for sort array with required sort algorithm:

```
private static void selectionSort(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] >= arr[i])
                continue;

            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

*Input:*

```
int[][] arr = {
        { 19, 44, 16, 39, 26 },
        { 42, 6, 30 },
        { 44, 37, 0, 46 },
        { 37, 42, 48, 19, 40 } };
```

*Output:*

```
sortByColumn(arr) provides:
     0  6 16 19 19
    26 30 37
    37 39 40 42
    42 44 44 46 48

sortByRow(arr) provides:
     0 19 37 42 46
     6 26 39
    16 30 40 44
    19 37 42 44 48
```